# Read Image stored in Oracle in Long (Finacle)

Tags: c#

I want to read the image stored in Oracle Long datatype. Number of images are stored in a remote Oracle database in a column with datatype long. I just need to retrieve those images and show them on my aspx page. I could retrieve the image from database but when tried to caste it to byte array, it threw error that, string can not be converted to byte[]'. Anybody have any suggestions on how to retrieve these images stored in long column in the database. I have already tried various beginner techniques.

```
            OracleDataReader TableReader = null;
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["System.Data.OracleClient"].ConnectionString;
        using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            command = new OracleCommand("Select * From IMAGE_TABLE where CUST_ID ='xxxxxxxx' fetch  first 1 rows only", connection);
            command.InitialLONGFetchSize = -1;
            TableReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (TableReader.Read())       
            {
                try
                {
                    var tt = Convert.ToInt32(TableReader[14]);
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[tt];
                    //long bytesRead = TableReader.GetBytes(13, 0, bytes, 0, tt);
                    //FileStream file = new FileStream("d:\\Img1.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                    //file.Write(bytes, 0, (int)bytesRead);
                    //file.Close();

                    byte[] blob_ =System.Text.UTF32Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TableReader[13].ToString());
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(blob_))
                    {
                        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception rr)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where are you converting the data to a string (or value)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have tried all types of encoding and base 64 string is also not giving the proper result ,